# How to efficiently load complex objects in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i'm implement a web service that loads and saves a hotel contract. This is the class structure (simplified)

```
public class Contract
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Season> seasonList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> roomList { get; set; }
}

public class Season
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Contract contract { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Season_Date> season_DateList { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Contract contract { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contingent> contingentList { get; set; }
}

public class Season_Date
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Season season { get; set; }
}

public class Contingent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Season season { get; set; }
    public Room room { get; set; }
}
```

For the load method a need to load a contract with all it's details. I don't want to use include, because there are to many tables and fields involved and i fear, that the resulting query is way to complex. 
Is there a way to load the season_date and contingent records using the contract id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lazy Loading, which means related entities will be loaded from the database the first time you try to access them (though this doesn't work well with serialization). You configure lazy loading on the `Configuration` property of your `DbContext` class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; 
    }
}
```

Relation properties need to be virtual, but you have done that already.

And if you know the contract id already, then why can't you just do the below?

```
var contract = myDbContext.Contracts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == idIWant);
```

More information on loading related entities is available [on this msdn page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: hi. Lazy Loading would do the trick, but it is not very efficient, when i already know, that i need the full object graph. If i have 5 seasons and 2 dates per season, that using lazy loading i get  7 queries to the database (contract + list of season + 5 x list of season_date). but using a join to the contract or building a in (id list) query, the same data could be fetched in 3 queries (contract + list of season + list of season_date by contract-id).